# Do you know rings without involutions, auto-anti-isomorphics? In that case, what is the minimal example?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings

Do you know rings without involutions, but auto-anti-isomorphic (isomorphic to their opposite)? In that case, what is the minimal example?

If a ring has an involution f, then f is an anti-automorphism; but there can be auto-anti-isomorphic ring without involutions.

Comment: By involution you probably mean an involutive self-map that is an anti-automorphism. So you want the existence of an anti-automorphism, but none being an involution (=being of order 1 or 2).

Comment: I don't see right away if any central simple algebra over $\mathbf{Q}$ might do the job.

Comment: 2x2 upper triangular matrices over a field are isomorphic to their  opposite.  I don't know if an obvious involution but maybe there is one

Comment: I suppose you exclude commutative rings...

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly it's excluded by the assumptions (the identity in a commutative ring is an involutive anti-automorphism)

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg yes in upper triangular $2\times 2$ matrices there's an obvious involutive anti-automorphism: $\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ 0 & d\end{pmatrix}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}d & b\\  0 & a\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: This is answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3797004/does-a-ring-isomorphic-to-its-opposite-always-admit-an-involution with a division algebra

Comment: There is an earlier, yet non-division such example in https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0081233 . Basically, any path algebra of a finite poset admitting an anti-automorphism and no involution will work. There is a 12-elements poset with this property in the last section.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg for everything to be complete one needs to have no involutive anti-automorphism as ring (=$\mathbf{Z}$-algebra), not just as $K$-algebra. So it would be nice to check that the criterion in the Morandi-Sethuraman-Tignol linked there applies to algebras over $\mathbf{Q}$ (in the sense that there are examples), which is possibly immediate but not to me.

Comment: @YCor In the paper in the answer I linked to they give examples over Q

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg great, this thus answers the question, it might be answered here too. Do you know what degree they have?

Comment: @YCor, I don't know the details.  I just saw the old stackexchange with google